# Curl Scraper working on localhost but not on online servers

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, scrapy, file-get-contents

I am trying to scrape https://www.gst.gov.in

```
echo $html = file_get_contents("https://www.gst.gov.in");
```

This code works perfect on localhost but not on the server.
I have tried using different serves with various curl methods with custom headers and referrers but no luck. On the server, I get a connection timeout error.

If I use any other https URL or another site it works fine. the problem is with this specific URL can anyone help in scraping this page also if anyone can tell if the remote server is blocking the request then how to bypass this.

Comment: i get a time out trying from my browser, sounds like the site is a little flaky.

Comment: When you ping www.gst.gov.in, what did you get?

Comment: @IdontDownVote it's probably a geographical lock, they block all IP's except Indian IP's, your IP is not indian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a government website - it's most likely blocking any IPs from geographical region that is not local.

i.e. your server needs to be in India or have Indian proxy since you are trying to download Indian government page.

Comment: why would it time out and not return a 403 or other response?

Comment: @IdontDownVote it's a firewall that simply drops all packets from non-indian IPs, it's simpler to set up and more robust against DDoS attacks to simply drop all packets, compared to actually returning any kind of response, like a http response.

Comment: yes i think you are right as i tried too access the website using proxy in chrome and its not working. will try to use proxy method. - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do check once if it works after removing config files like .htaccess. If you are using Html dom then extension hiders might cause trouble (my view). For eg. the code mentioned below causes trouble with simple Html dom:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```